# my modem-router not giving ip address and default gateway

Tags: router, modem, gateway

my modem-router not giving ip address and default gateway. i can't access my modem-router.

please help me.

when i type ipconfig /all in cmd, this is what i got:

C:\Users\PC1>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

```
Host Name  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : PC1-PC
Primary Dns Suffix . . . . . . . . . . :
Node Type  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled . . . . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled . . . . . . . . . . : No
```

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . . . . :
Description  . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8102E/RTL8103E Family PCI-E Fast Ethernet NIC <NDIS 6.20>
Physical Address . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-E0-B3-00-70-84
DHCP Enabled . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled  . . . . . . : Yes
Link-Local IPv6 Address  . . . . . . . : fe80::1c83:6ef3:68f4:7b36%11<Preferred>
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address . . . . : 169.254.123.54<Preferred>
Subnet Mask  . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
Default Gateway  . . . . . . . . . . . : 
DHCPv6 IAID  . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 234938547
DHCPv6 Client DUID . . . . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-14-51-A2-3B-00-E0-B3-00-70-84

DNS Servers  . . . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                         fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                         fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
NetBIOS over Icpip . . . . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Tunnel adapter isatap.<4A6DF01B-391C-4CA0-9EDE-E6D5750B54B0>:

```
Media State  . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . . . . :
Description  . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
Physical Addres  . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled . . . . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled  . . . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting all devices?

Comment: Assuming you have a physical connection, your computer is probably not the problem... Try restarting the modem.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the router's IP address (eg 192.168.1.1 /24), you can set a static IP on your machine in the same subnet (eg 192.168.1.2 /24) to communicate with and configure the router.

Lookup the router's user guide and find which IP is used by default and if the router assigns addresses using DHCP by default. Reset the router to factory defaults - there is usually a small button on the back or on the bottom of the device to accomplish this. If the router still does not assign IP addresses, you can set yourself with a static IP in an attempt to reach the router.

Comment: its really weird that i can't find any small hole and a button for facrtory reset.

where should i go to assign a static IP...
i usually access my router with 192.168.1.254, but can't open it now.

Comment: What is the make and model? You can set a static IP in the TCP/IPv4 settings of your network adapter. You can likely use an address like 192.168.1.100, subnet mask 255.255.255.0, default gateway 192.168.1.254. I would first focus on resetting the router.